# How to change the path of `npm` install `dependency` in `package.json`

Tags: npm

I have the `package.json` in which i would like to change the path of the `dependecy` how to do that?

here is my josn file:

```
{
  "name": "a2app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "self",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9", /developement/lib/ - how to add this?
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can change the path in the `package.json` file, if you want this you can change the path at the time of importing in the index.html. but why you want do the same ?

Comment: Because, I have a folder called `development` from their i am trying to access the `node_moudles` to my index file. but i am getting error on server. not files are loading

Comment: than try using `<script src="Development/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>` in your index.html.

Comment: no, it is required to step back from the `development` folder. But i am setting base folder as 'developement` in the `gulp`. so nothing is loading

Comment: try to figure out the exact path in the `network` tab under `console` and check if the files are loading from the seteled path or not